# How to proxy an ad url in IMA SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

In Interactive Media Ads SDK: I need to find a moment when ad url is known and replace it by another url.

I download VAST xml manually and pass it to request like this:

```
IMAAdsRequest(adsResponse: self.vast, adDisplayContainer: self.container, contentPlayhead: self.playHead, userContext: nil)
```

Now I need to find first place when url to ad is know (and modify it). How do I do it?
I am using IMA with AVPlayer.